# build and import a Cython module in AWS Glue job written in Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, cython, aws-glue, python-module

In order to speed up the execution of an ETL job, I've implemented a regression algorithm in Cython "regression.pyx" rather than python.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any documentation, how I can integrate properly in AWS Glue job.

I would like to import the Cython regression module in the python glue job as follows:

```
from regression import reg
```

Usually, the Cython script has to be built with a setup.py script, then it can be imported. What is the best way to integrated properly in AWS glue job?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify an external library location when you are creating the job.

[image]

You just upload the .zip or .whl file to S3 and specify the path.

More information on that [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-libraries.html).

Buildspec for my CodePipeline:

```yaml
BuildGlueModules:
    Type: AWS::CodeBuild::Project
    Properties:
      Artifacts:
        Type: CODEPIPELINE
      Environment:
        ComputeType: BUILD_GENERAL1_MEDIUM
        Image: aws/codebuild/standard:4.0
        Type: LINUX_CONTAINER
      Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-BuildGlueModules
      ServiceRole: !Ref CodeBuildRole
      Source:
        Type: CODEPIPELINE
        BuildSpec: !Sub |
          version: 0.2
          phases:
            install:
              runtime-versions:
                python: 3.8
            pre_build:
              commands:
                - python3 setup.py bdist_wheel
            build:
              commands:
                - aws s3 sync ./dist/ s3://my-bucket/glue_modules
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I want to do it also this way. But to import a cython script, you have to build it first with a setup.py file. Any idea how to do it with aws glue jobs.

Comment: That is not possible to do only with Glue. I build a AWS CodePipeLine, which takes my code from my Git repo, runs the setup.py and copies the build folder to S3.

Comment: Hey Robert, thank you for reaching out, it seems like a good idea. Can you give me please more details about your approach and implementation? thank you in advance.

Comment: I've added my CodePipeline snippet for CloudFormation. If I could help you, a upvote or accept on my answer would be appreciated.